# mixing binary and real-valued features with SGD

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, feature-selection, binary-data, gradient-descent

I'm going to be using a logistic regression model and using SGD to determine the feature weights.  Is it OK for me to use a mix of binary and real features, without doing anything like scaling or normalization, and just leave it to SGD to give me a model with weights that will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Binary features have a natural scale, so there is no need to rescale them. The real valued features need to be normalized by subtracting the mean and dividing by the range.

Comment: Is it necessary, though, in logistic regression?  Wouldn't gradient  descent find suitable coefficients regardless of whether I scaled the parameters or not?

Comment: Rescaling has the effect of making the surface of the gradient of your error less elliptical, allowing you to tune the step-size for an epoch more sensibly. Cross-validate with and without normalization. If you don't have too much data (<500,000 observations), compare the results with bfgs.